# How to get nock working in react&ts unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, react-redux, nock

I am looking at [this](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html) link to unit test redux action creators: . This is what my unit test looks like:

```
 it('creates FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS when fetching todos has been done', () => {
    nock('http://example.com/')
      .get('/todos')
      .reply(200, { body: { todos: ['do something'] } })

    const expectedActions = [
      { type: 'fetch_todos_request' },
      { type: 'fetch_todos_success', body: { todos: ['do something'] } }
    ]
    const store = mockStore({ todos: [] })

    return store.dispatch(actions.fetchTodos()).then(() => {
      // return of async actions
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
    })
  })
```

In my jest solution I use react+typescript. I got a gut feeling my error has to do with the typescript config, this is the error:

```
src\__tests__\redux-test.tsx
  ● async actions › creates FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS when fetching todos has been done

    TypeError: nock_1.default is not a function

      at Object.it (src/__tests__/redux-test.tsx:17:9)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

The nock module is installed but why am I getting this error and how can I get rid of this?

Comment: Recheck your imports.

Comment: It is installed in node modules and imported